# Standard deviation of weighted sums of random distributions with weights random but fixed

Tags: distributions, variance, random-variable

Let $a,b,c,d$ be independent normally distributed random variables.  I'm aware that the following distributions:

$$c a + d b$$

$$(c+d)a$$

both have the same standard deviation ($=\sqrt{2}$ if $a,b,c,d$ have unit variance).

I'm interested in the statistics generated by the following process:
Let $a,b$ represent vectors containing a large number of samples, while $c,d$ each represent a single sample.  Then what is the expected standard deviation of the two distributions above?  Using the MATLAB code below, I get mean standard deviations of approximately $1.25$ and $1.125$, respectively.

```
N=100;
for m=1:100000
    a = randn(N,1);
    b = randn(N,1);
    c = randn(1);
    d = randn(1);

    x(m)=std(c*a+d*b);
    y(m)=std((c+d)*a);
end

mean(x)
mean(y)
```

If possible, I'd like to characterize the distribution of standard deviations fully, but a way of deriving the mean would be helpful too.

My apologies if this question is too easy (I hope so!).

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing.  What does it mean for a vector to "contain ... samples" and, when $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are vectors *of different lengths,* what do their products mean?  In any event, whatever you are doing looks like it might possibly be answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699, which shows how to compute moments of inner products of multinormally distributed variates.  (Yes, I read the `R` code, but it's still unclear what you're trying to do, because it seems to be evaluating *standard deviations* of *components* of vectors, not variances at all.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comments.  I've rephrased the question in terms of standard deviation instead of variance.  I agree that I don't know the appropriate vocabulary to describe my question, which is part of why I can't find the answer myself, and is also the reason that I've included code -- to make the meaning clear.  The products you refer to are just scalar times vector, so I think the meaning is clear.  Let me know if it's still not.

Comment: To be clear, there are no inner products here, so the link in your comment is unrelated.  All the products are scalar x vector.

Comment: Thanks. But what distinction are you making between "standard deviation" and "expected standard deviation"?  The code does not clarify that.  BTW, there definitely *are* inner products here; you just have to see them. For instance, the sums and sums of squares involved in computing `std(c*a)` can be expressed as the inner product of `rep(c,100)` with `a` and the inner product of `rep(c^2,100)` with `a^2`; quite possibly the latter could be dispensed with by considering the square of the former. Under some interpretations of your question, the latter isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the first case, if $N$ is large, the mean of the standard deviations should be about $\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.25$ and in the second case it should be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 1.128.$

This can be calculated using the sampling theory of the normal distribution. In the first case, $\mathrm{Var}(ca + db) = c^2 \mathrm{Var}(a) + d^2 \mathrm{Var}(b)$. Now, $1/(N-1)$ times the variance of a sample of size $N$ from the standard normal has a chi-square distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom, so $\mathrm{Var}(a)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(b)$ are $\chi^2_{N-1}/(N-1)$ random variables. In your case, $\chi^2_{99}/99$. If you are interested in $N \rightarrow \infty$, then the variance of the the chi-square random variable divided by $N-1$ will tend to zero and $\mathrm{Var}(a)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(b)$ will be approximately $1$. You are left with
$$sd(ca+bd) \sim \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$$
where $c$ and $d$ are standard normals. This is a [chi-distrbution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) with $2$ degrees of freedom. Wikipedia says that its mean is $\sqrt{2}\Gamma(3/2) = \sqrt{2}(1/2)\sqrt{\pi} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, which is about $1.25$.

The second case is very similar. The same sort of argument gives an approximate distribution for $sd((c+d)a)$
$$sd((c+d)a) \sim \sqrt{(c+d)^2}$$
But $(c+d)$ is normal with standard deviation $\sqrt{2}$, so $\frac{(c+d)}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a standard normal. Therefore, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{(c+d)^2}$ is a $\chi_1$ random variable and its mean is $\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}$. Since $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ it follows that the mean of $\sqrt{(c+d)^2}$ is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ which is approximately $1.128$.

---

**tl;dr** If $N$ is large, the first is $\chi_2$ with mean $\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}$, the second is $\sqrt{2}$ times $\chi_1$ with mean $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.