# Convergence of the Matérn covariance function to the squared exponential

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance, convergence, gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

> The Matérn covariance function converges to the squared exponential
>   covariance function.

Many sources, amongst them the [GPML book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf#page=7) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function#The_Gaussian_case_in_the_limit_of_infinite_%CE%BD), 
state this result. None of them provide details.

I am looking for references that provide details and a proof. In particular, I wonder about the kind of convergence.

Answer (score 6):

The Matérn function can be written in terms of

$$f_{\nu}(x) = C_\nu |x|^{\nu} K_{\nu}\left(|x|\right)\tag{*}$$

where $C_\nu$ is a normalizing constant (to make the value of $f_\nu(0)$ equal to $1$) and $x = \sqrt{2\nu}\, d/\rho.$

(This agrees with the [Wikipedia notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function#Definition) where $x$ represents $\sqrt{2\nu} d/\rho.$)

As shown at [Moment generating function of the inner product of two gaussian random vectors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699/moment-generating-function-of-the-inner-product-of-two-gaussian-random-vectors/51717#51717) (using elementary techniques),

> the Matern function is proportional to the density function for the distribution of the dot product of two random vectors where each has $2\nu+1$ components and all components are independently distributed as standard Normal variables.

Such an inner product is the sum of the $2\nu+1$ independent and identically distributed products of corresponding components of the vectors.  Each of those is the product of two independent standard Normal variables $X$ and $Y$ and therefore has mean $0$ and variance

$$\operatorname{Var}(XY) = E[(XY)^2] = E[X^2]E[Y^2] = (1)(1) = 1.$$

Consequently the inner product has mean $(2\nu+1)(0) = 0$ and variance $(2\nu+1)(1)=2\nu+1.$

The [Central Limit Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734) asserts that the normalized versions of these inner products therefore approach a standard Normal distribution almost surely.  The effect of normalization is to replace $x$ by the square root of its variance, $x\sqrt{2\nu+1},$ which changes the probability element $f_{\nu}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ by

$$f_{\nu}(x\sqrt{2\nu+1})\mathrm{d}(x\sqrt{2\nu+1}) = \sqrt{2\nu+1} f_{\nu}(x\sqrt{2\nu+1})\mathrm{d}x.$$

This differs from $(*)$ (where we may take $\rho=1$ without any loss of generality, because it merely establishes the distance unit of measurement) only insofar as $x$ is multiplied by $\sqrt{2\nu+1}$ instead of $\sqrt{2\nu}.$ Since the ratio of these terms approaches unity, in the limit it makes no difference which one is used.  Consequently, **the convergence is almost sure.**

One tiny nicety is that because $f_\nu$ is normalized to have a peak height of $1,$ which is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ times the peak height of the standard Normal density, *the convergence is to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ times the standard Normal density rather than the density itself.*  Re-introducing the scale factor $\rho$, we have deduced--using purely statistical thinking!--that

> $$\lim_{\nu\to\infty} f_\nu(d) = \exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{2\rho^2}\right)$$ almost surely.

This agrees with what [Wikipedia asserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function#The_Gaussian_case_in_the_limit_of_infinite_%CE%BD).

[image: ![Figure]

*This plot shows graphs of $f_2$ (blue), $f_5$ (red), and the limiting Gaussian (gold).  The convergence occurs by pulling the tail in to fill out the peak.*

Comment: +1 for the details, I learned something here. Do you happen to know a citable reference as well?

Comment: A few geostatistical texts describe the Matérn family, but I am not aware of any that use the approach I took here to demonstrate convergence to the Gaussian (squared exponential) form.