# The Spectral Density for the Matérn Covariance Function

Tags: gaussian-process

In [Paper1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02267v2.pdf), we're working with a linear functional approximation to a Gaussian Process, shown below.

In equation (8) of this paper, we have

$$V=\mathrm{Diag}(S^{-1}(\sqrt{\lambda_j}))$$ (there's already a typo: a missing square root)

where $V^{-1}$ is the column variance of the matrix-normal distribution, and $S$ is the spectral density of the covariance function we've decided to use for the Gaussian Process. The $\lambda_j$'s are the eigenvalues at each we must evaluate the spectral density.

Is this $V$ matrix well defined (typo free, except for the square root)?

I ask this because the authors state that eq. 8 is a generalization to the multidimensional output case of the prior defined in  eq. 3:

$$f(x)\approx \sum^m_{j=1}f^{(j)} \phi^{(j)}(x), \text{ with } f^{(j)}\sim N(0, S(\sqrt{\lambda_j}))$$

where the $\phi^{(j)}$ are the eigenfunctions corresponding to the eigenvalues above. This is the linear functional approximation.

However, unless for the Matérn covariance function has a spectral density such that $S^{-1}(\sqrt{\lambda_i})=(S(\sqrt{\lambda_i}))^{-1}$, I do not see how it's correct...

Addendum: The Matérn Class of functions is given by $$k_M(r)=\frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\frac{r\sqrt{2\nu}}{l}\right)^{\nu} K_{\nu}\left(\frac{r\sqrt{2\nu}}{l}\right)$$ where $r=\Vert x-x'\Vert$. The function $K_\nu$ is the Modified Bessel of the 2nd kind. And its spectral density is given by:
$$S(x):=\frac{2^D\pi^{\frac{D}{2}}\Gamma(\nu+D/2)(2\nu)^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)l^{2\nu}}\left(\frac{2\nu}{l^2}+4\pi^2 x^2\right)^{-(\nu+D/2)}$$, where $D$ is the dimension of $x$.

P.S.: For the definition of Matérn Covariance function and its spectral density, see [chapter 4 of this book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)

Paper1: "Computationally Efficient Bayesian Learning of Gaussian Process State Space Models", Andreas Svensson, Arno Solin, Simo Särkkä and Thomas B. Schön (2016).

Paper2: "Hilbert Space Methods for Reduced-Rank Gaussian Process Regression", Arno Solin, Simo Särkkä, (2014)

Comment: I think you will need to be more explicit: I couldn't find any clear definition of the Matérn function in paper 1 and a search shows that "Matérn" doesn't even appear in paper 2.  It's frustrating to readers that you require them to hunt through technical materials just to understand what you're trying to ask, so please make it explicit in your question.

Comment: @whuber In paper 2, they use the Matérn covariance function to create fig.1. 

For a definition of the Matérn covariance function, here's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function

Comment: [I am well aware of this covariance function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387113/), thank you.  My comment was posted on behalf of readers who will be parsing your post carefully and will realize that an answer very will might depend on specific, precise definitions that are neither explicit nor immediately in evidence in your references.

Comment: @whuber the definitions used in the paper are supposedly the same as in the book whose link I just added to the main question. This book is the first reference in Paper1 and it's also referenced in Paper2.

Comment: Just a friendly nudge--do you seriously think many qualified people will read your question when they have to look up three separate sources in order to understand it?

Comment: Could you add 1. complete references to the papers (title, authors etc.) 2. pointers to where exactly the conflicting notation appears (Something like  "in [1] Eq. (3) is $A=\lambda_i+7$ while in [2] Eq. (9) is $A=\sqrt{\lambda_i}+6$").

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I've edited /changed a bit the question. I now am sure of at least 1 typo. I'm looking if there's more. Thanks ;)

Comment: @whuber I think it's now much better. What is your opinion?

Comment: +1 because I wish to see advanced questions more often (although I agree with the question being posed in a not so accessible way).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings thanks. As soon as I get some free time, I'll try to improve on that. ;)

Comment: What is "$S$"??